# How to pass QVector<Custom_Q_GADGET> to QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have QObject class with 2 properties:

```
class Foo : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVector<Namespace1::Namespace2::Item> items READ getItemVector)
    Q_PROPERTY(QVector<QString> tests READ getTestVector)
    ...
}

QVector<Namespace1::Namespace2::Item> Foo::getItemVector() const
{
    return _item_vector;
}

QVector<QString> Foo::getTestVector() const
{
    return _test_vector;
}
```

Everything is ok with `QVector` of `QString`s in the QML, but I was not able to pass `QVector` of `Namespace1::Namespace2::Item`s.

Output to QML console gives me:
`QVariant(​QVector<Namespace1::Namespace2:​Item>)​` for console.log(foo.items)
and 
`length = undefined` for console.log(foo.items.length)

What I have found out from the Qt documentation:

> These sequence types are implemented directly in terms of the underlying C++ sequence. There are two ways in which such sequences can be exposed to QML: as a Q_PROPERTY of the given sequence type; or as the return type of a Q_INVOKABLE method.

...

> In particular, QML currently supports: ... QList< QString >... and all registered QList, QVector, QQueue, QStack, QSet, QLinkedList, std::list, std::vector that contain a type marked with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE.

As I understand, everything boils down simply to:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Namespace1::Namespace2::Item)
```

Besides this:

> Some types are registered automatically and do not need this macro: Pointers to classes derived from QObject, QList< T >, **QVector< T >**, QQueue< T >, QStack< T >, QSet< T > or QLinkedList where T is a registered meta type

However, I also tried to declare metatype(without luck, obviously):

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QVector<Namespace1::Namespace2::Item>)
```

and also tried to register metatypes(without any luck as well):

```
qRegisterMetaType<Namespace1::Namespace2::Item>("Namespace1::Namespace2::Item");
qRegisterMetaType<QVector<Namespace1::Namespace2::Item>>("QVector<Namespace1::Namespace2::Item>");
```

The `Item` by itself is a `Q_GADGET`:

```
namespace Namespace1 { namespace Namespace2 {
    class Item
    {
    Q_GADGET
        Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ getName CONSTANT)

    public:
        Item();
        Item(const QString& name);
        Item(const Item& origin);
        Item(Item&& origin);
        ~Item();

    private:
        QString _name;

    public:
        Item& operator=(const Item& rhs);
        Item& operator=(Item&& rhs);

    friend QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& out, const Item& item);
    friend QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream& in, Item& item);
    friend QDebug operator<<(QDebug debug, const Item& item);
    }
} }
```

What am I missing?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try using pointers: `QVector<ns1::ns2::item*>`? I realize I often go the `QList<QObject*>` way... not ideal but it works since I'm casting in QML.

Comment: @Amfasis Thank you for the reply. Yes, I do use pointers in QML time to time, but not in this case. Moreover, I have to care about ownership because I need a copy.

Comment: I spend some time trying to get this working, but can't really... I think you should consider `QQmlListProperty` which you can also make readonly, or `QAbstractListModel`. What do you mean with the ownership?

Comment: @Amfasis Thank you for the effort and I have same negative results. Finally, reimplemented with QML List Property as you have suggested. Btw, how do you think, should I report a bug at bugreports.qt.io?

Comment: It seems there is already some reported: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-73399 and I get the impression they will postpone to Qt 6

Answer (score 0):

The "traditional" way of doing this is to convert each element to a QVariant, and pass collection as a QVariantList

```
QVariantList MyClass::getFooCollection(void) const
{
    QVariantList list;

    for (const auto& l: fooCollection_)
    {
        list.append(QVariant::fromValue(l));
    }

    return list;
}
```

The metatype system declaration and registration you have shown are required